# Finding a point which has shrink nicely using Hardy Littlewood maximal function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> **Question:** Let $E$ be measurable subset of $[0,1]$ with $m(E)=99/100$. Then there exists $x \in [0,1]$ such that $\forall r \in (0,1)$, $m(E \cap B(x,r)) \geq r/4$.
>
> Hint: Use Hardy-Littlewood maximal function and its inequality.

**My attempt:** We know that 
$$m(E \cap B(x,r)) \geq r/4 \iff \frac{m(E \cap B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))} \geq r/4 \cdot \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}= \frac{1}{8}.$$
Also, by the Folland's 3.22 Exercise, if $E$ is Borel set, then $$D_{E}(x) = \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{m(E \cap B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))} = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{ if }x \in E \textrm{ a.e.} \\ 0 & \textrm{ if }x \in E^{c} \textrm{ a.e.} \end{cases} $$
Hence, by regularity, $E = F \cup N$, where $F$ is $F_{\sigma}$ set and $N$ is null set. So, we know that almost every $x \in F$ has $D_{E}(x)=1$. Hence, we can find that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $$r<\delta \implies \frac{m(E \cap B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))} > 1-\epsilon.$$

However, as you know, it is not sufficient condition that $\forall r \in (0,1)$, $\frac{m(E \cap B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))} \geq \frac{1}{8}$ I considered use Hardy Littlewood maximal theorem directly to $f=1_{E}$, but it doesn't give any useful information. This theorem gives that $\{ Hf(x)>\frac{1}{8}\}$ is bounded not that it exists and holds for all $1>r>0$.

Could you give any hint for this problem?